# Too many theano runtime errors

Tags: python, deep-learning, conda, tensor, theano

I created a conda envirinment with python 3.9 and Installed theano 1.0.5. But when I write this simple program, I encounter many errors. This is my code:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T

x = T.vector('x')
W = T.matrix('W')
b = T.vector('b')

dot = T.dot(x, W)
out = T.nnet.sigmoid(dot + b)
```

and this is my errors:

```
F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\scalar\basic.py:2324: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bool` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  self.ctor = getattr(np, o_type.dtype)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Projects/Python/theanoTutorial/firstExample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan_opt.py", line 60, in <module>
    from theano import tensor, scalar
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from theano.tensor.basic import *
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\basic.py", line 20, in <module>
    from theano.scalar import int32 as int32_t
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\scalar\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\scalar\basic.py", line 2371, in <module>
    convert_to_bool = Cast(bool, name='convert_to_bool')
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\theano\scalar\basic.py", line 2324, in __init__
    self.ctor = getattr(np, o_type.dtype)
  File "F:\Projects\Python\Environments\condaTheano\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

What's the problem?

I think there are some conflicts or incompatibility between python version and packages. But I don't know what exactly it is.

I tried with python 3.8 and theano 1.0.4, but anything didn't change. Also I changed the versions of some packages like mkl, but nothing changed.
Thanks.

Comment: Your package [is not maintained anymore](https://github.com/Theano/Theano)

Comment: TL; DR: downgrade `numpy`. As the errors says, numpy deprecated and later remove some names. `theono` used those names, and hasn't been updated in several years to fix its incompatibility with modern `numpy`. `theono` also doesn't specify which versions of numpy it's compatible with in its distribution metadata, which is why an incompatible version of numpy could be installed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my numpy version to 1.16.5 and problem solved.